# Bootstrap4 Cards, overlaying a button over the card image?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm currently experimenting with Bootstrap4 and I have an issue with the images. Basically what I want to achieve is the following:

[Bootstrap4 Card with top right button on image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uYnY.png)

I want to overlay the "3-dot" button over the image in the top right. The button will act as a dropdown menu with a few options like edit, share etc... The code to make the card without the button is:

```
<div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-block">
    <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card 
title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
</div>
</div>
```

I've tried enclosing the the card-img-top and a button with a div tag, but the image shifts out of bounds. Any tips on achieving this? Thanks!

Comment: Either use the image as background image and add height to it. Or add position absolute to the three dot button, and position it by top: 5px; right: 5px.

Comment: @Aijaz Thanks, the second suggestion worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use the image as background image and add height to it. Or add position absolute to the three dot button, and position it by top: 5px; right: 5px.